# Is Philosophy the source of all other fields of study?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, history-of-philosophy, psychology, foundationalism

[CONTEXT]
I started a self-education plan to learn computer science from foundations. then, I found my self in need to learn electrical engineering, after that I understant that I should learn Physics -essentially Electromagnetism- the thing that requires mathematics -essentially Calculus (derivations, integrals..)-.. here I found myself in a really huge quantity of knowledge that makes me wondering about its foundations and I was truly surprised how much the foundations of maths are related to philosophy..
all this transitions are motivated by my desire of checking the foundations of any new discipline and this what guided me -obviously- to Philosophy..
[CONTEXT]
**So, is philosophy the source or the foundation of all sciences.. what is the foundations of philosophy?.. can psychology explain to me how philosophizing is done?**

Comment: NO. In ordr to build a bridge you have to know the relevant laws of physics and the rlevant mathematical techniques used to perform modelling and calculation. To do this, the philosophical foundations of math and physics are not necessary. If you are interested into "foundations", this is a discipline by its own.

Comment: Also No, as per @MA above. In addition, you don't need physics, E&M, EE for computer science, but you definitely need some math (more modern algebra than calculus). Perhaps take a look at https://www.u-cursos.cl/ingenieria/2010/2/CC3102/1/material_docente/bajar?id_material=322214 (a .pdf of Papadimitriou's  book), and/or https://www.u-cursos.cl/ingenieria/2010/2/CC3102/1/material_docente/bajar?id_material=322208 (a .zip containing a .djvu of Sipser's book). These are both roughly junior/senior undergraduate level (for USA).

Comment: If you try to learn from foundations you will never learn anything, foundations are used to collect and organize what you already know on some level. No wonder you are overwhelmed, you do not need electromagnetism, calculus or philosophy to start learning computer science. It is pretty autonomous and electronic implementation is incidental to what it is about. The more relevant "foundations" are logic and the theory of algorithms, but even those won't do you much good until you have a solid practical grasp on programming itself.

Comment: @Conifold  Actually my plan of learning is based on learning from Zero.. for example I am familliar with binary and javascript and some of php.. even python. what I'm trying is to start learning -for example learning computer science- from the point where we don't have a computer I mean from the first beginning.. I think this is good because it gives me full understanding of what I learn and how this science or discipline develops.

Comment: Already Plato realized that there is no learning from zero. A look at CS history may be helpful for motivation and ideas but do not expect the world from it. Nothing will give you "full understanding", and attempting it may just clutter your mind with irrelevant details. What is you *purpose* in learning computer science, is it for art's sake, as it were? Try to focus on some specific problem, or puzzle about it, something suited to *your* skillset, not zero, and keep it in the back of your head while reading up. It may help focus your efforts and help you organize and imprint what you learn.

Comment: @Conifold this it truly convinving, but often, I have a question of where this came from .. and its relationship with another concept for example. By the sequence of these questions it is true that I often find myself somewhat far away from what I want to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, is philosophy the source or the foundation of all sciences.. what
>   is the foundations of philosophy?.. can psychology explain to me how
>   philosophizing is done?

You can find the following quote in the following link.

The quote:

> One morning Sri Bhagavan quoted from a journal the following sentence:
>   "Where psychology ends, philosophy begins" and added his own remark,
>   "Where philosophy ends spirituality begins."

http://www.arunachala.org/newsletters/1992/jan-feb

This means, the subject itself is the foundation of philosophy.  When each subject ends, its philosophy begins.

Answer (score 2):

Philosophy is traditionally considered as the "mother" of all other disciplines. It is also true that when you get deeply into the foundations of nearly any discipline, it begins to overlap with philosophy, which is why the doctorate for most disciplines is called the Doctorate *of Philosophy* (PhD).

The foundation of philosophy is the question "Why?"

Comment: you cleared the relation between philosophy and other disciplines fair enough. But your statement about the foundations of philosophy may make philosophic thinking necessarily a teleological thought.

Comment: I disagree. The foundation of Philosophy is: "What To Flag?"