# When will a Philosopher stop asking questions?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-mind

Apparently Philosophers keep asking questions and "ALL" of their questions involve some form of contradiction, or some form of critical analysis. What will be the "end game" where philosophy dies?

Comment: Nonduality. . .

Comment: Philosophy IS the "art" of asking (deep... we hope) questions: most of them stay unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

According to a hardcopy I furtively glimpsed when summoned to headquarters for a formal reprimand, the plan is to stop when all the answers have been found. I understand no target date has yet been set for the final cessation, but since the list of questions still hasn't been finalised, I suspect it may still be some millennia away.

Comment: I thought Wittgenstein had got the job done? ;)

Comment: @MarcoOcram +1 for the subtle irony of your answer, hitting the nail on the head :-)

Comment: We need to develop an AI that comes up with more questions, that way we can all keep our jobs!

Answer (score 1):

If there is mind no one will stop asking questions. When it becomes still it stops asking questions.

You might get the answer here: [Is Philosophy the source of all other fields of study?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/48547/is-philosophy-the-source-of-all-other-fields-of-study)

These are the 4 parts of mind (for study purpose) https://www.aryamargayoga.org/post/chitta-the-4-level-matrix-of-the-mind

Usually, if someone is in an awake state, at least some simple questions will be asked.

Doubts can end only through self-realization.

Comment: And not having a doubt doesn't mean that one knows everything.

Comment: @ScottRowe : I would say, he knows the meaninglessness of asking doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. The philosophical questions will continue to be raised as long as there is a craving to have to sex. Sex produces children who are unaware of the philosophy and they will ask the same questions again.On the other hand, if we ask, can a final book of philosophy can be written which contains all the answers? Then also it is not possible to end questioning, because books can not explain God. God can not be explained using only books. It must be felt. God must be experienced in order to understand. Moreover, there is a hidden knowledge which we do not discuss directly. We discuss that knowledge using sensual signs. Even on this site you can not raise every question!! But if you are smart enough you can raise that question indirectly.

Comment: "*The questionings will continue until morale improves.*"